# Query DynamoDb on a field other then the primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a dynamo table from c#. This is the definition of the table

```
public class EmailArchive
    {

        [DynamoDBHashKey]
        public string SystemId { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBProperty]
        public string EmailMessageId { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBProperty]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBProperty]
        public string CaseId { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBProperty]
        public string Headers { get; set; }
}
```

So far to fetch data from the table I was using the

```
[DynamoDBHashKey]public string SystemId { get; set; }
```

And the code to get records out of dynamo was this

```
var config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig{
                OverrideTableName = table
};
var email = await _dynamoDBContext.LoadAsync<EmailArchive>(systemId, config);
```

It all works fine however now I want to query this table on two additional columns

```
 [DynamoDBProperty]public string Status { get; set; }
 [DynamoDBProperty]public string CaseId { get; set; }
```

Can you please show an example of how to query the table with additional columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a [secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html).

Local Secondary Index (LSI) if you'll know the SystemId when you make the query; an LSI has the same has key as the table, but a different sort key.

Global Secondary Index (GSI) if you will only have Status, CaseId; a GSI supports a different hash & sort keys from the original table.

Note: adding a LSI requires the table to be deleted and re-created.

Comment: Creating a GSI on CaseId will work well but wanted to call out that indexing on Status may lead to high cardinality assuming that the bulk of the items in the table will have the same status (presumably something like "closed" or "resolved"). This is not a problem for small tables but if you have lots of cases, you may want to reconsider indexing on "Status" and perhaps create a surrogate attribute like a boolean "ActiveCase" that is only present for active cases and index on that..